# Using an external syntax highlighter in vim

Tags: vim

I have access to a syntax highlighting program for an internal-only language. Is there any way in which I could get vim to call this program to perform syntax highlighting? I figure that it's worth seeing if this is possible before I write my own syntax file, since it's quite complex (not to mention prone to change). The program in question could be quite easily customized to output in a new intermediate format (it's only currently outputting HTML), if that would make things easier.

Comment: I don't think Vim has a built-in notion of this sort of thing. It seems like it might be possible to kludge, by writing syntax which matches your highlighter's formatting tags (be they html or something else), then ignores or conceals the tags themselves - but from what I'm finding right now, the hl-Ignore group and the conceal mechanism are part of nonstandard patches...

Comment: It is probably possible to do what you're asking, but I have written a syntax highlighter for VIM (the Delphi 2010+ one) and the experience was much easier than I expected.  Seriously, it won't take you more than an hour or two.  Just look at a few that are provided with Vim.

Comment: agreed with CJH, Vim's syntax highlighting is pretty easy. One option could be to try to make your tool output a vim syntax script :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest to write a quick throwaway script in the language of
your choice to convert the output of the program in question to the Vim
highlighting syntax. You mentioned the program is prone to change, but
its output format can be easily customized: using your own conversion
script (which parses the programs output format) you could easily stay
up-to-date with the latest changes (just run your script again). And as
others have mentioned: creating a new syntax file is [really easy](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Creating_your_own_syntax_files) in Vim,
so it's up to the complexity of the programs output how hard this actually is.

Comment: I guess this is the closest you can get.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use vim job/channels to communicate with external process and highlight text using textprops.

Type `:help channel` and `:help textprop` in vim to get more info.

This method is used to implement treesitter highlighting in [vim-treesitter](https://github.com/mattn/vim-treesitter) plugin